# Cannot fire bootstrap-confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I created the following popover confirmation using **bootstrap-confirmation** and want to fire this confirmation onClose event of a Dropdownlist. Although I can get the console log on every close of Dropdownlist, I cannot display the confirmation window onClose as well. Is there a way for manually firing it?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupId, new SelectList(Model.Groups, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { data_toggle = "confirmation" })

$('#GroupId').on('select2:close', onClose)

function onClose(evt) {
    console.log('close...'); //this line is executed

    //I think the problem is related to this part. I might be using it on the wrong section
    var Confirmation = require('confirmation-popover');
    var confirm = new Confirmation({
            rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
            // other options
            selector: '[data-toggle="confirmation"]',
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            placement: 'top',
            btnOkIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            btnOkClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
            btnOkLabel: 'Yes',
            btnCancelIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            btnCancelClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
            btnCancelLabel: 'No'
        });
        confirm.show(el);
}
```

Comment: $("#GroupId").on("change",function(e){ onClose(e);}) should work, Please try.

Comment: The problem is not related to calling the method onClose, actually the problem is related to how to fire the bootstrap-confirmation and I have no idea how to define it properly in order to manual firing. Any idea?

Comment: https://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/#   and when you want to fire it? on selection of option in dropdown?

Comment: In the **onClose** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO attached: Hope this is what you asking for.

```js
$("select").on("change",function(){
  $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation();
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
<script src="http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/dist/bootstrap-confirmation2/bootstrap-

confirmation.min.js"></script>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<select  class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation"
        data-btn-ok-label="Continue" data-btn-ok-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"
        data-btn-ok-class="btn-success"
        data-btn-cancel-label="Stoooop!" data-btn-cancel-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"
        data-btn-cancel-class="btn-danger"
        data-title="Is it ok?" data-content="This might be dangerous">
  <option value="volvo">Option 1</option>
  <option value="saab">Option 2</option>
  <option value="vw">Option 3</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It is very close what I am looking for and now the only problem using the option parameters in confirmation(). I tried to insert the option parameters ("placement", etc.) in the confirmation, but did not works. How can I use them in the confirmation?

Comment: actually am outside right now no access to pc so can not update the demo but you can set a parameter like data-option inside the same select on change event, i mean append a attribute on change and get then inspect the element in browser for the open confirmation popup , after that the ok button in that confirmation append a id and and option in the button, if that helps mark answer as accepted and if not i will update the demo tomorrow. Best wishes.

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. I solved the problem by using both **$('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({ // Options and Callbacks });** and **function onClose(evt) { $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation('show'); }** at the same time.

Comment: On the other hand, I marked your post as answer but it would be better if your edit it by including the solution on my previous comment above.

Comment: I appreciate you figured out own your own, thats really great!